# Vertically centering an image and a text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and its grid layout and in one column I am trying to get an image pulled to the right and a text pulled to the right next to the image as well while they should both be vertically centered. With the image it's easy - I made the class img-responsive and added padding to that column and a pull-right to the image so it sits well, however the text doesn't seem to center whatever I try.

I tried applying this to the column:

```
.center{
    display : table-cell;
    vertical-align : middle;
    float:none;
}
```

and it seemed to work when there's only text, however with the image included it won't.

Here is my code for the column:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-md-push-4 equalcolumn" id="namecolumn">
        <img class="pull-right img-circle img-responsive" id="myimage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/03/Super_Mario_Bros._box.png" alt="">
        <h4 class="pull-right" id="nametext">Welcome!</h4>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#namecolumn {
    padding: 1vh; 
}
.img-responsive {
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: h4 is a block element, so set it as inline-block and give vertical-align:middle; to both img and h4 , so they center to each other on the baseline.

Answer (score 1):

`h4` is a block element, so set it as `inline-block` and give `vertical-align:middle;` to both `img` and `h4` , so they center to each other on the `baseline`.

```
#myimage, #nametext {
    display:inline-block;/* defaut display of img tag */
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't seem to work. If it helps, I have set height: 12vh; for all .equalcolumn, maybe that disturbs it somehow?

Comment: then add `.equalcolumn{line-height:12vh;}` and reset `line-height` to 1.2em to childs of `.equalcolumn *{line-height:1.2em;}` . from that , you can only have one line

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cretae 2 wrapper divs that have a value of `display: table` and `display: table-cell`. Then you can use `vertical-align: middle`.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1750/

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.wrapper-inner {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper-inner">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-md-push-4 equalcolumn" id="namecolumn">
        <img class="pull-right img-circle img-responsive" id="myimage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/03/Super_Mario_Bros._box.png" alt="" />
        <h4 class="pull-right" id="nametext">Welcome!</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: h4 still needs to be set inline to stand aside img :)

Comment: I don't follow. The concept example I have displayed can be applied to any element or group of elements.

Comment: he was saying that he wanted the text standing on the right side of the img , that's my about comment :)  http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1751/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to vertically center float elements like col-md-3 and so on use this example http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height